# Circle of Negative Radius in the Argand Plane

Tags: complex-numbers, circles

Recently while doing some problems I came across the phrase " a circle of negative radius in the complex plane." I am unable to come to a conclusion with regards to the definition of "negative radius" and am not sure whether it can exist even in the argand plane.

A quick follow-up:- Are circles with imaginary radii possible as well and if so then how do we interpret and express them mathematically ?

Comment: In my understanding, the radius (joining a point and some fixed center) has to be non-negative. Explanation: If the circle is embedded in a topological space, that is equipped with a distance function, and the radius is some distance function d(x,C) for point x on circle and C center of circle, then by definition radius is positive as metrics $d: X\times X\to[0,\infty)$ for some set $X$, have codomain in $\mathbb{R}_+$.

Comment: If I were given $z=-re^{i\theta}$, then I would interpret it as $z=e^{i(\theta+\pi)}$. So it just means that the starting point of the curve is elsewhere than z=r. Obviously, the same way of thinking would apply if the radius is complex.